# VB.NET and MySql saving to two tables; parent table and child table

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Here I am trying to save information to two tables (using vb.net); `students`(parent table) and `guardians`(child). The relationship between the tables has already been created, Foreign Key(`guardian id`) which auto increments. Below is my code, your help will be appreciated.

```
    Dim cn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader

    cn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost; user id='root'; password='' ; database='dbname'"
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cn.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = "Select stud_id, firstname, lastname, dob, sickness, sex, pin, payment_type, level_stream FROM students WHERE stud_id = '" & txtstud_id.Text & "'"
    'cmd.CommandText = "Select guardian_id, firstname1, lastname1, sex1, occupation, relationship, address, cell, telephone, email FROM guardians WHERE guardian_id = '" & txtgid.Text & "'"
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.HasRows Then
        MsgBox("Student ID already exist!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Checkpoint")
    Else
        cmd.Dispose()
        dr.Dispose()
        cmd.CommandText = " Insert into students (stud_id, firstname, lastname, dob, sickness, sex, pin, payment_type, level_stream) Values ('" & txtstud_id.Text & "','" & txtfname.Text & "','" & txtlname.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "','" & txtsickness.Text & "','" & cmbsex.Text & "','" & txtpin.Text & "','" & cmbpay_opt.Text & "','" & cmblevel_stream.Text & "')"
        'cmd1.CommandText = " Insert into guardians (guardian_id, firstname1, lastname1, sex1, occupation, relationship, address, cell, telephone, email) Values ('" & txtgid.Text & "','" & txtfname1.Text & "','" & txtlname1.Text & "','" & cmbsex1.Text & "','" & txtoccupation.Text & "', '" & txtrelationship.Text & "','" & txtaddress.Text & "', '" & txtcell.Text & "','" & txttel.Text & "','" & txtemail.Text & "')"

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Information successfully saved", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Saving data succeed")
        txtstud_id.Clear()
        txtstud_id.Focus()
        txtfname.Clear()
        txtlname.Clear()
        DateTimePicker1.Text = String.Empty
        cmbsex.Text = String.Empty
        txtpin.Clear()
        txtsickness.Clear()
        txtgid.Clear()
        txtfname1.Clear()
        txtlname1.Clear()
        cmbsex1.Text = String.Empty
        txtoccupation.Clear()
        txtrelationship.Clear()
        cmbpay_opt.Text = String.Empty
        txtaddress.Clear()
        txtcell.Clear()
        txttel.Clear()
        txtemail.Clear()
        cmblevel_stream.Text = String.Empty

    End If
```

Comment: Do not concat text and values to make a query.  Use SQL parameters

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: use different command variables to execute. Like cmd1, cmd2, and cmd3

Comment: @PNP does that mean I should also declar those command varriables and open a connection, execute and close connection for each one of them?

Comment: @Plutonix please make an example on that

Comment: Once you create connection its enough to use for other commands. But you have to declare seperate commands and bind with connection. And also execute seperate queries with those commands. But remamber to dispose commands before begin other. And if you close connection before you start other commands.. then you have to open it again.

Comment: You need to do your own research - there are gobs and gobs of posts here showing the right way to do it.  In fact, if you study the articles on MSDN, you might lean how to INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE with almost no code using a DataAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for separate executions according to what I said in comments
Please read comments in the code segment.

```
Dim cn As New MySqlConnection
//''1st Commnad variable
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
 //''2nd Commnad variable
Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand
 //''3rd Commnad variable
Dim cmd2 As New MySqlCommand

Dim dr As MySqlDataReader

cn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost; user id='root'; password='' ; database='dbname'"

cmd.Connection = cn

cn.Open()

cmd.CommandText = "Select stud_id, firstname, lastname, dob, sickness, sex, pin, payment_type, level_stream FROM students WHERE stud_id = '" & txtstud_id.Text & "'"

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

If dr.HasRows Then
    MsgBox("Student ID already exist!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Checkpoint")
    cmd.Dispose()
    dr.Dispose()
    cn.Close()
Else
    cmd.Dispose()
    dr.Dispose()
    //'In this case you don't want to close the connection because you executing another queries too. 
    //'otherwise you have to check connection status and do open or close according to the status.
    //'For Example
    //'If (cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed)Then
    //' cn.Open()
    //'End if



    cmd1.Connection = cn
    cmd1.CommandText = " Insert into students (stud_id, firstname, lastname, dob, sickness, sex, pin, payment_type, level_stream) Values ('" & txtstud_id.Text & "','" & txtfname.Text & "','" & txtlname.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "','" & txtsickness.Text & "','" & cmbsex.Text & "','" & txtpin.Text & "','" & cmbpay_opt.Text & "','" & cmblevel_stream.Text & "')"
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cm1.Dispose()


    cmd2.Connection = cn
    cmd2.CommandText = " Insert into guardians (guardian_id, firstname1, lastname1, sex1, occupation, relationship, address, cell, telephone, email) Values ('" & txtgid.Text & "','" & txtfname1.Text & "','" & txtlname1.Text & "','" & cmbsex1.Text & "','" & txtoccupation.Text & "', '" & txtrelationship.Text & "','" & txtaddress.Text & "', '" & txtcell.Text & "','" & txttel.Text & "','" & txtemail.Text & "')"
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd2.Dispose()


    //'Close when its over. otherwise you have to check whether connection is open or not before you start trans queries to database server. See else statement comments for example.
    cn.Close()

    MsgBox("Information successfully saved", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Saving data succeed")
End If
//'Disposing cmd and dr
```

You can use same command but you have to think how to use it. Once you execute a command or datareader  you have to Dispose it. And more concern about connection property to Closed or Open.